# CPU speed drops to 0.61/0.79GHz and remains there whenever I unplug the charger

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power, cpu-speed

My laptop is a dell latitude e6520

Windows 10 Pro 21H2

Intel Core i5-2520M CPU @ 2.50GHz processor

and a 12 GB RAM.

I recently changed it's motherboard and whenever the laptop's charger is unplugged, the CPU speed drops to either 0.61GHz or 0.79GHz and remains there until the the charger is plugged back in or the system is rebooted.

However, if I boot up the system without the charger plugged in, it runs fine. If I put the charger in and remove it, The CPU speed drops. What could be going on?

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? Have you updated firmware? Why did you replace the mainboard to begin with.

Comment: @music2myear well, I replaced the board because an IC was heating up and the PC wouldn't charge. I've updated the OS and BIOS so far, I've monitored the core temperatures, it's usually between 60°C - 80°C. It seems the CPU is throttling whenever I unplug the charger. I downloaded throttlestop and managed to turn off throttling. Still don't know why the CPU does that in the first place?